# Whole file patch versus delta patch installs

Tags: installation

I'm putting together a service release install for our customers.  I'm creating a minor update patch.  Is it recommended to use the delta patch method for updating files, or does the "whole file" method produce more reliable results?  Has anyone seen an advantage of one over the other (other than the smaller size for delta patches)?

I'm using an InstallShield Basic MSI project and Windows Installer 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a bug in XP version of MSPATCHA.DLL, which is a protected file that can't be easily replaced, the whole file method is more reliable. In fact, that is my only option to distribute patches to users running XP.

Comment: Thanks!  I had basically come the the conclusion that whole file was working better, but I didn't know about the XP bug.  Thank you!